# XNA simple state machine doesn't do anything

Tags: xna

I'm working on a project for my Video Game Design class where I basically had to find some bugs in some code, fix it, and then convert it all into a state machine using an enumeration. I've pasted the initialize, update, and draw methods below, and as you can see, I've commented out the old code before converting it into a state machine. Everything was working fine before with all the if/else statements, but now that I've converted it, it doesn't actually do anything. It displays the standing sprite in the starting position, but pressing the keys does absolutely nothing.

INSTANTIATING VARIABLES

```
    Texture2D heroineTexture, dive, duck, jump, stand;
    int yVelocity, jumpVelocity, diveVelocity;
    Rectangle player;
    enum State
    {
        Standing,
        Jumping,
        Ducking,
        Diving
    };
    State state;

    KeyboardState kb, oldkb;
```

INITIALIZE

```
        oldkb = Keyboard.GetState();
        jumpVelocity = -10;
        diveVelocity = 15;
        yVelocity = 0;
        heroineTexture = stand;
        state = State.Standing;
        player = new Rectangle(0, 430, 50, 40);
        base.Initialize();
```

UPDATE

```
        kb = Keyboard.GetState();
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        player.Y += yVelocity;

        switch (state)
        {
            case State.Standing:
                if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.J))
                {
                    state = State.Jumping;
                    yVelocity = jumpVelocity;
                    heroineTexture = jump;
                }
                else if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                {
                    state = State.Ducking;
                    heroineTexture = duck;
                }
                break;
            case State.Jumping:
                if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                {
                    state = State.Diving;
                    heroineTexture = dive;
                    yVelocity = diveVelocity;
                }
                break;
            case State.Ducking:
                if (!kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                {
                    state = State.Standing;
                    heroineTexture = stand;
                }
                break;
        }


        if (player.Y >= 430)
        {
            state = State.Standing;
            player.Y = 430;
            yVelocity = 0;
            heroineTexture = stand;
        }

        //if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.J) && oldkb.IsKeyUp(Keys.J))
        //{
        //    if (!isJumping && !isDucking)
        //    {
        //        isJumping = true;
        //        yVelocity = jumpVelocity;
        //        heroineTexture = jump;
        //    }
        //}
        //else if(kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        //{
        //    if(!isJumping)
        //    {
        //        if(isDiving)
        //        {
        //            yVelocity = diveVelocity;
        //        }
        //        else if(!isJumping && !isDiving)
        //        {
        //            isDucking = true;
        //            heroineTexture = duck;
        //        }
        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        isJumping = false;
        //        heroineTexture = dive;
        //        isDiving = true;
        //    }
        //}
        //else if(!kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        //{
        //    if(isDucking)
        //    {
        //        isDucking = false;
        //        heroineTexture = stand;
        //    }
        //}

        oldkb = kb;
        base.Update(gameTime);
```

Comment: Look at when you are setting the state. More specifically: `if (player.Y >= 430)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally: set a breakpoint on every line where you SET the state, start debugging and you'll find the culprit.

Anyway. In your commented code, you did the player.y >= 430 check BEFORE handling the states, but now you do it afterwards.

You are basically setting the state but not changing the position, so, if I guess correct, your player was standing (>= 430), you set the state and immediatly afterwards (before actually changing the player.y) the player is still standing and you setting the state back to standing.

This is just guessing from your code snippet because the location of the "if player.y >= 430" actually is called at a different time now

you need to do this:

> player.Y += yVelocity;

AFERT the switch/case but BEFORE the

> if(player.y >= 430)